# WARN web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Unable to deliver notification

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I did get this error when I've upgraded from 5.0 to 5.1.

It was related to https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4778.
See http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/WARN-web-o-s-s-n-NotificationService-Unable-to-deliver-notification-td5035238.html for details.

It was a bug and it was supposed to be fixed in 5.1.1 with https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6566 as Simon Brandhof stated.

Now I've upgraded to 5.1.1 and I'm still having the same problem.

```
2015.06.09 09:52:48 WARN  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Unable to deliver notification Notification{type='issue-changes', fields={new.resolution=FIXED, old.status=OPEN, projectKey=xxxxxx, new.status=CLOSED, ruleName=Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented with Javadoc, reporter=null, assignee=xxxxxx, message=Document this public constructor., old.reso
lution=null, projectName=xxxxxxxx, componentKey=null, key=d7571ab9-ac49-41c9-9973-35d4a1ee83cf}} for user xxxxx via EmailNotificationChannel
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:76) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
        at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.getSingleResult(JpaDatabaseSession.java:207) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.getSingleResult(JpaDatabaseSession.java:238) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.user.HibernateUserFinder.findByLogin(HibernateUserFinder.java:47) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.deliver(EmailNotificationChannel.java:98) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.server.notifications.NotificationService.dispatch(NotificationService.java:200) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.notifications.NotificationService.deliver(NotificationService.java:190) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.computation.step.SendIssueNotificationsStep.doExecute(SendIssueNotificationsStep.java:83) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.computation.step.SendIssueNotificationsStep.execute(SendIssueNotificationsStep.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationService.process(ComputationService.java:89) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationContainer.execute(ComputationContainer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.computation.ComputationThread.run(ComputationThread.java:58) [sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1232) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1225) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4073) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1577) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 264Â 434Â 682 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to
ur application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.ction validity before use in yo      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3661) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisÃ© (pipe)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I don't have access to the Jira, so I cannot add a comment to the bug.
Can you please help me with this.

---

Here's the database configuration from the system information page :

```
Database
Database    MySQL
Database Version    5.5.37-log
Username    sonarqube@xxxxxxxxxxx
URL     jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxx/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
Driver  MySQL Connector Java
Driver Version  mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 ( Revision: jess.balint@oracle.com-20141014163213-wqbwpf1ok2kvo1om )
Version Status  UP_TO_DATE
Pool Active Connections     2
Pool Max Connections    50
Pool Initial Size   0
Pool Idle Connections   3
Pool Min Idle Connections   2
Pool Max Idle Connections   5
Pool Max Wait (ms)  5000
Pool Remove Abandoned   false
Pool Remove Abandoned Timeout (seconds)     300
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait_timeout on your MySql instance? Starting with SQ 5.0, more and more analysis processing is done on server side, so this might explain why some DB requests take time to be executed.

Comment: Increasing the wait_timeout is a workaround, but it's not the solution. The problem is not a long request that takes time to execute. The problem is a connection to the database that is not closed and is reused later when sonarqube wants to deliver notifications. So if sonarqube doesn't delivers mails for 2 days, I must increased the wait_timeout as long as 2 days!! This is a regression, see bug #4778 and # 6556. It was supposed to be fixed in 5.1.1...

Comment: My feeling is that there is probably some configuration issue on your side, because we don't experience such an issue with our public instance of SonarQube (http://nemo.sonarqube.org) which runs 5.1.1 on MySql 5.6.19. Can you please add the following information to your question: content of the "Database" section of the "System Info" page in your SonarQube instance.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam I've added my database configuration in my question. I've not changed my configuration since 5.0. I'm using the same configuration as the default one given in the sonar.properties file.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Did you run into this problem with nemo and sonar 5.1.0? Does nemo send email notifications? If so does nemo send notifications after the wait_timeout?

Comment: Yes, notifications are activated on Nemo (I receive daily ones), and we never had this problem on Nemo. But maybe your instance sends far more notifications than Nemo. Could you try setting the "sonar.notifications.delay" property (in your conf/sonar.properties file) to something like "10"? This may help reducing the time required to query the DB for notifications to send. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Notifications+-+Administration.

Comment: My sonarqube instance is sending a couple of notifications almost each hour during daytime. It's not sending notifications during the night, so I'm beyond the wait_timeout (8 hours per default) in the morning and I'm getting this error. The workaround for the moment is to restart sonarqube each morning. I do have apply the "sonar.notifications.delay" to 10 seconds, but I'm not sure it will resolve this issue.

Comment: Any update on this?  I am seeing the same error with SonarQube 5.1.2 and MySQL 5.6.26. Is there a JIRA I can watch?

Comment: We are facing the same problem here. (SonarQube 5.1.1 and MySQL 5.6.26). But we have another strange effect regarding this issue.
Since we upgraded to 5.1.x, we have never received any “New issues” mails. We can see the above exception in the log.
On the other hand, the “New Quality Gate Status” notifications are sent without problems. We get them regularly and have never seen any exceptions on those in the log files.