# How to set "pool remove abandoned" property in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

TL;DR: How can I configure SonarQube to remove abandoned DB connections?

We recently upgraded to SonarQube 5.1.2 and I'm now seeing connection errors from the Notification service (as described [elsewhere on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30852758/944849)).

While trying to diagnose, I noticed the "Pool Remove Abandoned" setting in the System Info.

```
DATABASE
Database    MySQL
Database Version    5.6.26-log
....
Pool Remove Abandoned   false
Pool Remove Abandoned Timeout (seconds) 300
```

I wondered if changing this to 'true' would have any impact on the errors, so I looked in [`conf/sonar.properties`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties) for this property, and I do not see it.  All I see is

```
#sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
#sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

and I cannot tell if one of these is the property to change or perhaps just uncomment.  There doesn't seem to be a "sonar.jdbc.removeAbandoned" property or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> sonar.jdbc.removeAbandoned=true
>
> sonar.jdbc.removeAbandonedTimeout=60

sonar.jdbc.* is used org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource